# Matching pairs that occur in multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm simulating a population of male and female birds, and females select a mate to breed with. The population is a data frame, and each row is a unique individual, its ID, the ID of its mate (if it paired), its sex, and whether or not it has paired.

I'm tracking who pairs with who so I can keep track of what traits offspring will get later. The data for which females pair and with who is in the data frame, but I'd like to have the reciprocal relationship in there too (so rows where selfID is D and E should have mateID's A and B, respectively). Is there a simple way to do this? Nothing's coming to mind at the moment...

```
df <- structure(list(selfID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), mateID = c("D", 
"E", NA, NA, NA), sex = c("female", "female", "female", "male", 
"male"), paired = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

selfID mateID sex    paired
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <lgl> 
1 A      D      female TRUE  
2 B      E      female TRUE  
3 C      NA     female FALSE 
4 D      NA     male   NA    
5 E      NA     male   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach:

```
for(i in df$mateID[!is.na(df$mateID)]) {
  df$mateID[df$selfID == i] <- df$selfID[df$mateID == i & !is.na(df$mateID)]
}

df$paired[!is.na(df$mateID)] <- T

df
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# selfID mateID sex    paired
# <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <lgl> 
# 1 A      D      female TRUE  
# 2 B      E      female TRUE  
# 3 C      <NA>   female FALSE 
# 4 D      A      male   TRUE  
# 5 E      B      male   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution that uses `merge` with itself (no looping is done).

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df, df, by.x = "selfID", by.y = "mateID", all.x = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(mateID = ifelse(is.na(mateID), selfID.y, mateID),
           paired = ifelse(is.na(paired.x), paired.y, paired.x)) %>%
    select(selfID, sex = sex.x, mateID, paired)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions which both use *self join*:

#### 1. dplyr

This is a somewhat polished-up version of [PoGibas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893559/3817004) which uses `left_join()` instead of `merge()` and `coalesce()` instead of base R's `ifelse()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("selfID" = "mateID")) %>% 
  mutate(mateID = coalesce(mateID, selfID.y), 
         paired = coalesce(paired.x, paired.y)) %>% 
  select(selfID, mateID, sex = sex.x, paired)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
>   selfID mateID sex    paired
>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <lgl> 
> 1 A      D      female TRUE  
> 2 B      E      female TRUE  
> 3 C      NA     female FALSE 
> 4 D      A      male   TRUE  
> 5 E      B      male   TRUE
> ```

#### 2. data.table

For the sake of completeness (and aware that the question has been tagged with [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)), here is a one-liner which uses `data.table`'s ability to perform *updates in a self join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df, on = .(selfID = mateID), `:=`(mateID = i.selfID, paired = TRUE)]
df
```

> ```
>    selfID mateID    sex paired
> 1:      A      D female   TRUE
> 2:      B      E female   TRUE
> 3:      C   <NA> female  FALSE
> 4:      D      A   male   TRUE
> 5:      E      B   male   TRUE
> ```